# Openresty: how to use a different nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx, openresty

In Ubuntu 20.04:
I have openresty installed and it is running well.
It uses the default `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`.

I want to instead use a new custom `nginx.conf` file in `~/conf/nginx.conf`.

How can I ask openresty to run on this new conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer:

```
ubuntu@john:~$ openresty -help
nginx version: openresty/1.19.9.1
Usage: nginx [-?hvVtTq] [-s signal] [-p prefix]
             [-e filename] [-c filename] [-g directives]

Options:
  -?,-h         : this help
  -v            : show version and exit
  -V            : show version and configure options then exit
  -t            : test configuration and exit
  -T            : test configuration, dump it and exit
  -q            : suppress non-error messages during configuration testing
  -s signal     : send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload
  -p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /usr/local/openresty/nginx/)
  -e filename   : set error log file (default: logs/error.log)
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: conf/nginx.conf)
  -g directives : set global directives out of configuration file
```

use

```
openresty -c filename
```